# Trying to save scroll placement between navigation clicks, but on a nav drawer, not the whole page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I am trying to save the placement of the scroll bar on my left hand navigation drawer, so if someone clicks one of the 20 options on the left navigation, the scroll bar will land where they left off. But I am getting "Navscroll is null" every time.

The code I am working with is a huge jumble of 20 years worth of adding the next new thing. So most recently they added in react and things of the sort. I am also fresh out of bootcamp which is a big stresser.

The component is AppDrawer and I am working in the \AppNavDrawer.tsx. Below is the previous developers AppNavDrawer, where I added the lines I've mark with '//ADDED' comment.

Where am I going wrong in my code?

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Drawer,
  SwipeableDrawer,
  Theme,
  useMediaQuery,
  List,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { Page, usePageContext } from 'components/Page/Provider';
import { AppNavDrawerItem, AppNavDrawerItemProps } from './AppNavDrawerItem';
import { makeStyles, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

// iOS is hosted on high-end devices. We can enable the backdrop transition without
// dropping frames. The performance will be good enough.
// So: <SwipeableDrawer disableBackdropTransition={false} />
const iOS =
  typeof navigator !== 'undefined' &&
  /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent);

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
  createStyles({
    paper: {
      width: 280,
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
      top: '5em',
      paddingBottom: '5em',
    },
    html: {
      fontsize: '1em',
    },
    '@global': {
      '*::-webkit-scrollbar': {
        width: '0.4em',
      },
      '*::-webkit-scrollbar-track': {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
      },
      '*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
        backgroundColor: '#DBDAD9',
        borderRadius: '1em',
      },
      '*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover': {
        backgroundColor: '#75716E',
      },
    },
  })
);

interface ReduceChildRoutesProps {
  activePage?: Page | null;
  page: Page;
  depth: number;
  items: React.ComponentElement<AppNavDrawerItemProps, any>[];
  onClose: () => void;
  state: string | null;
  handleStateChange: (input: string) => void;
}

function reduceChildRoutes({
  activePage,
  items,
  page,
  depth,
  onClose,
  state,
  handleStateChange,
}: ReduceChildRoutesProps) {
  const { title } = page;
  if (page.children && page.children.length > 0) {
    const topLevel = activePage
      ? activePage.pathname?.indexOf(`${page.pathname}/`) === 0
      : false;
    // items.push(<Divider />);
    items.push(
      <AppNavDrawerItem
        depth={depth}
        key={title}
        tab={page.tab}
        topLevel={topLevel && !page.subheader}
        openImmediately={topLevel || Boolean(page.subheader)}
        title={title}
        icon={page.icon}
        handleStateChange={
          title === 'Quick Actions' ? () => { } : handleStateChange
        }
        state={title === 'Quick Actions' ? 'Quick Actions' : state}
      >
        {renderNavItems({
          activePage,
          depth: depth + 1,
          pages: page.children,
          onClose,
          state,
          handleStateChange,
        })}
      </AppNavDrawerItem>
    );
  } else {
    page =
      page.children && page.children.length === 1 ? page.children[0] : page;

    items.push(
      <AppNavDrawerItem
        depth={depth}
        key={title}
        title={title}
        tab={page.tab}
        href={{
          pathname: page.pathname,
          search: page.query,
        }}
        onClick={onClose}
        icon={page.icon}
        handleStateChange={handleStateChange}
        state={state}
      />
    );
  }
  return items;
}

interface RenderNavItemProps {
  pages: Page[];
  depth: number;
  activePage?: Page | null;
  state: string | null;
  onClose: () => void;
  handleStateChange: (input: string) => void;
}
function renderNavItems(options: RenderNavItemProps) {
  const { pages, ...restProps } = options;
  return (
    <List disablePadding style={{ paddingTop: '0' }}>
      {pages.reduce(
        (items, page) => reduceChildRoutes({ items, page, ...restProps }),
        [] as any[]
      )}
    </List>
  );
}

export interface AppDrawerProps {
  mobileOpen?: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  onOpen: () => void;
  className?: string;
}
export const AppNavDrawer: React.FC<AppDrawerProps> = (props) => {
  const { mobileOpen = false, onClose, onOpen, className } = props;
  const { activePage, pages } = usePageContext();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const mobile = useMediaQuery<Theme>((theme) => theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));
  const navTitle = sessionStorage.getItem('navTitle');
  const [state, setState] = React.useState<string | null>(navTitle);

  const drawer = React.useMemo(() => {
    const handleStateChange = (input: string) => {
      if (
        input === 'Premises' ||
        input === 'Notifications' ||
        input === 'Premises Administration' ||
        input === 'Animal Identification Management' ||
        input === 'AIMS Management Tasks' ||
        input === 'Administration'
      ) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('navTitle', input);
      }
      setState(input);
    };
//ADDED STARTS HERE
    let prevScrollPos = 0;
    var navscroll = document.getElementById('drawer')



    if (navscroll != null) {
      navscroll.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
        prevScrollPos = navscroll!.scrollTop;
      });

      navscroll.addEventListener('unload', function () {
        localStorage.key(prevScrollPos)
      });

      navscroll.addEventListener('load', function () {
        const savedScrollPos = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('scrollPosition')!);

        if (savedScrollPos) {
          navscroll!.scrollTop = savedScrollPos;
        }
      })}
    else {
      console.log("Navscroll is null")
    }
  
    ;
//ADDED ENDS HERE


  const navItems = renderNavItems({
    onClose,
    pages,
    activePage,
    depth: 0,
    state,
    handleStateChange,
  });
  return <>{navItems}</>;
}, [activePage, onClose, pages, state]);



return (
  <nav>
    {mobile ? (
      <SwipeableDrawer
        disableBackdropTransition={!iOS}
        variant="temporary"
        open={mobileOpen}
        onOpen={onOpen}
        onClose={onClose}
        ModalProps={{
          keepMounted: true,
        }}
        PaperProps={{ className: classes.paper }} // Apply paper styles
      >
        {drawer}
      </SwipeableDrawer>
    ) : (
      <Drawer
        id="DrawerName" //ADDED
        variant="permanent"
        open
        className={className}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.paper,
        }}
      >
        {drawer}
      </Drawer>
    )}
  </nav>
);
};
```

Thank you in advance for any help.